# Type 'Dispatch<Action>' is missing the following properties from type 'IAuthContext': type, payload

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get an error "Type 'Dispatch' is missing the following properties from type 'IAuthContext': type, payload" how to fix I do not understand

This is my code:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from "react";

const AuthStateContext = createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);
const AuthDispatchContext = createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);

const authReducer = (state: IAuthState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
      };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`);
  }


export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, { user: null })

  return (
    <AuthDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <AuthStateContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </AuthStateContext.Provider>
    </AuthDispatchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuthState = () => useContext(AuthStateContext);
export const useAuthDispatch = () => useContext(AuthDispatchContext)
```

> Its not work, error: "Type 'Dispatch' is missing the following
> properties from type 'IAuthContext': type, payload  TS2739"

Answer (score 2):

`IAuthContext` defines an object with properties `type` and `payload`, so basically a redux action.

In these two lines, you say that the **value** of your two contexts is either `null` or an `IAuthContext` action:

```
const AuthStateContext = createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);
const AuthDispatchContext = createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);
```

But here, the value which you pass to the context provider is not an `IAuthContext` action, it's the dispatch function:

```
<AuthDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
```

`dispatch` is a function which takes the `IAuthContext` action as a argument.  It is not the action itself.

You have a mismatch between the declared value type and the provided value type, so one of those two things needs to change.  Based on your naming, I think you are intending for the context value to be a dispatch function, so the one which needs to change is the declared type of the context.

```
const AuthDispatchContext = createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);
```

should be something like

```
const AuthDispatchContext = createContext<Dispatch<IAuthContext> | null>(null);
```

or

```
const AuthDispatchContext = createContext<((action: IAuthContext) => void) | null>(null);
```